# Variables in C not displaying?

Tags: c

I have all variables stored, but for some reason, they aren't adding up and giving me my total. (each bus number stores user input to enter amount of students)

```
allSuburbs= bus121+bus711+bus451+bus562+bus122+bus113+bus123+bus324+bus654;
northSuburbs= bus121+bus711+bus451;
southSuburbs= bus562+bus122;
eastSuburbs= bus113+bus123;
westSuburbs= bus324+bus654;



printf("Total students:\n",&allSuburbs);
printf("Total students from North Suburbs:\n",&northSuburbs);   
printf("Total students from South Suburbs:\n",&southSuburbs);
printf("Total students from East Suburbs:\n",&eastSuburbs);
printf("Total students from West Suburbs:\n",&westSuburbs);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `printf` is missing format specifiers (`"%d"`?) and you are passing the address of the variables (`&`) rather than their values, which I don't imagine is what you intended.

Comment: My friend, buy a good C book first.

Comment: When programming in C you need to make your compiler display (all) warnings. Don't try to run the program until your code compiles cleanly.

Comment: i appreciate the help. The numbers are now adding up but when running the code

Comment: printf("Bus121 %d:\n",bus121); scanf("%d", &bus121);

Comment: it displays a random number next to the bus numbers. Help please

Comment: That's because you're trying to write the value before you read it.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 what do you recommend??

Comment: @dbush that means what exactly?? kinda new to C

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the format string to get the values formatted into your message (the first argument of `printf`). Additionally, you should note that you probably want to just print the variables, not their addresses - so lose the `&` operator:

```
printf("Total students %d:\n", allSuburbs);
// Format string ------^
// No & here ------------------^
```

Comment: i appreciate the help. The numbers are now adding up but when running the code

Comment: printf("Bus121 %d:\n",bus121);
    scanf("%d", &bus121);

Comment: it displays a random number next to the bus numbers. Help please

Comment: you've got that the wrong way around - you have to read in the value and then you can print it out

Answer (score 1):

You've got 2 problems with your calls to `printf`

1) you're not actually telling `printf` where you want the values to appear - you need to add in the appropriate formatting codes

2) you're passing in a pointer to the variable

So for example

```
printf("Total students:\n",&allSuburbs);
```

should probably be something like

```
printf("Total students: %d\n",allSuburbs);
```

assuming that is that `allSuburbs` is an `int`